Slow Target Area Recognition with Vuforia SDK on Android
I'm having a problem with target zone recognition on an Android application I'm developing. When detecting a specific area, the process takes an abnormally long time to successfully identify the target area, even though it works fine with the iOS SDK.
Here are the additional details:

Device used: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8
Target area size: The target area I'm trying to detect is about 22 square meters.
Code snippet: Here's a code snippet that shows how I load and detect the area target.

 VuDevicePoseConfig devicePoseConfig = vuDevicePoseConfigDefault();
    devicePoseConfig.activate = VU_TRUE;
    vuEngineCreateDevicePoseObserver(engine, &devicePoseObserver, &devicePoseConfig, nullptr);

    VuAreaTargetConfig areaTargetConfig = vuAreaTargetConfigDefault();
    areaTargetConfig.devicePoseObserver = devicePoseObserver;
    areaTargetConfig.databasePath = "area_target_database.xml";
    areaTargetConfig.targetName = "area_target_database";
    areaTargetConfig.activate = VU_TRUE;
    areaTargetConfig.requireExternalPositions = VU_FALSE;

    vuEngineCreateAreaTargetObserver(engine, &areaTargetObserver, &areaTargetConfig, &areaCreationError);

 VuObservationList* obsList = nullptr;
 vuObservationListCreate(&obsList);
 vuStateGetObservations(state, obsList);

 int32_t listSize = 0;
 vuObservationListGetSize(obsList, &listSize);
   for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        VuObservation* obs = nullptr;
        if (vuObservationListGetElement(obsList, i, &obs) != VU_SUCCESS) {
            return;
        }
        if (poseInfo.poseStatus != VU_OBSERVATION_POSE_STATUS_NO_POSE) {
            VuMatrix44F modelView = vuMatrix44FMultiplyMatrix(renderState.viewMatrix, poseInfo.pose);
            VuMatrix44F deviceMatrix = vuMatrix44FInverse(modelView);

            x = deviceMatrix.data[12];
            y = deviceMatrix.data[13];
            z = deviceMatrix.data[14];

Has anyone else encountered similar problems with the Vuforia SDK on Android? Do you have any suggestions for improving area recognition performance?
Thanks in advance for your help!

I recommend adding more detail to your question. What is the size of the Area Target you are activating? What device are you using? Attach a screenshot of a Profiler to see if throttling occurs at runtime. If the space is not getting detected, see https://developer.vuforia.com/library/area-targets/best-practices-scanning-environment#choosing-environments for recommendations.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thank you for your suggestions. I've added more details in my question @thesbyro

Thank you for your reply. I have added code to my question @Community
